# Can I declare an object directly in the "if" expression?

Tags: c#, declaration

I am trying to use an object just for an expression but not sure if that is possible:

```
if ((new (Random)).Next(0,1))
{

}
```

This does not work, I would like to know whether it is even possible?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Considering `new (Random)` isn't a valid expression by itself, I don't see why you think it would work in an if expression.

Comment: I think you try to say `(new Random()).Next(0,1)` and this `Next` method returns `int`. But since if statement expect [boolean expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression) (and there is no implicit conversation between `int` and `bool`) it is too normal not working.

Comment: `if ((new Random()).Next(0,1) == 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work... Note that what you wrote had multiple errors (logical and grammar)

```
if (new Random().Next(0,2) == 0)
```

And you aren't **declaring** an object, you are **creating** an object.

The syntax to create an object is `new TypeName()` or `new TypeName {}`. If the constructor has parameters, you have to use the syntax `new TypeName(par1, par2)`.

Doing a `new Random().Next(0, 1)` is totally useless... because it will generate a random number between 0 and 1 excluded, so 0 and 0, so 0 :-)

Other "logical" error: a `Random` object should be reused, not created and used once and then discarded. This because a `Random` object "represents" a sequence of random numbers (based on the seed). If you create multiple `Random` objects in a short time, they'll often use the same seed, and generate the same sequence. `new Random().Next() == new Random().Next()` 99 times out of 100.

You can even do more **awful things** (note the bold)...

```
Random rnd;

if ((rnd = new Random()).Next(0, 2) == 0)
```

This because the assignment operator `=` "returns" the value assigned, so you are assigning `new Random()` to `rnd`, and then you are taking the assigned value and using it for the `.Next`. Note the additional brackets around the assignment.

If your question is really *Can I declare an object directly in the “if” expression?*, then the answer is no! You can't declare a new variable inside the `if` conditional expression... You can't do:

```
if ((Random rnd = new Random()).Next(0, 2) == 0)
```

The only keyword in C# that lets do it are the `for cycle`:

```
for (Random rnd = new Random()...
```

and the `using` (but this one is more limited, it can only work in `IDisposable`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize it using `()`. It still doesn't return any `boolean` result which is must for an `if` condition.

Do it like this:

```
if (new Random().Next(0,2) == 1)
```

Comment: this will always be false, see xanatos's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because

1. if condition only check for boolean condition .i.e true or false
2. Your statement neither return true or false
3. You statement in if condition returns void (or the variable defined)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to if(new Random().next(0,2)==0) and you shouldn't have any problems...

Comment: Actually, there will still be a compilation error since Random.Next(0,2) creates and integer value, not a boolean value.

Comment: That's right! I meant that it's possible to have it there